# extern template 'inconsistent explicit instantiations'

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Given

```
#include <vector>

// Case I: error
```

> error C2961: 'std::vector>': inconsistent
>   explicit instantiations, a previous explicit instantiation did not
>   specify 'extern template'

```
template class std::vector<int>;
extern template class std::vector<int>;


// Case II: fine
//extern template class std::vector<int>;
//template class std::vector<int>;

// Case III: fine
//extern template class std::vector<int>;
//template class std::vector<int>;
//template class std::vector<int>;

// Case IV: fine
//extern template class std::vector<int>;
//extern template class std::vector<int>;
//template class std::vector<int>;
//template class std::vector<int>;


int main()
{

}
```

I build the code with VS2015 Version 4.6 and see the C2961 error. However, I don't see the error with compiler http://gcc.godbolt.org/.

Is this a bug with VS2015?

Comment: `std::vector` takes at least two template arguments, not one. (The actual number is implementation-defined.)

Comment: @ildjarn Why wouldn't the defaults kick in?

Comment: @ildjarn Second argument of `Vector` is fully optional. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: @NO_NAME : It's optional when you're merely naming the type; it's not optional when you're _declaring_ the type.

Comment: clang also complains, about 'extern' explicit instantiations following explicit instantiations (without 'extern').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC and Clang are right to issue an error in this case. [temp.explicit]/11 in the standard says:

> If an entity is the subject of both an explicit instantiation
>   declaration and an explicit instantiation definition in the same
>   translation unit, the definition shall follow the declaration. [...]

`template class std::vector<int>;` is an explicit instantiation definition. The one with the `extern` is an explicit instantiation declaration.

---

Note that explicitly instantiating `std::vector<int>` is ill-formed in any case according to [namespace.std]/2:

> [...] A program may explicitly instantiate a template defined in the
>   standard library only if the declaration depends on the name of a
>   user-defined type and the instantiation meets the standard library
>   requirements for the original template.

Also note that cases III and IV are also ill-formed according to [temp.spec]/5:

> For a given template and a given set of *template-arguments*,
>
> - an explicit instantiation definition shall appear at most once in a program,
>
> [...]
>
> An implementation is not required to diagnose a violation of this
>   rule.